# Why I can't use variable that I defined in viewDidLoad in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I defined a variable in `viewDidLoad` But The problem is that I can't use that variable in the same View Controller outside of `viewDidLoad`.

Here is my code:

```swift
class ProfileSettingTableViewController: UITableViewController {

var userAccountMoney = String()

var headerList = ["account\(ProfileSettingTableViewController().userAccountMoney)" , "Help" , "" ]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userAccount = profileViewController().userMoney

    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa")
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: userAccount))
    userAccountMoney.append(numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: userAccount))!)

}
```

**this code compiles, but even if I define for example let a = 1000 I can't reach that outside `viewDidLoad`**

Comment: Edit your question with your current code and with error that you are getting

Comment: I Edited the question

Comment: `ProfileSettingTableViewController().userAccountMoney` will create a completely new instance of `ProfileSettingTableViewController` not the current one, Is your requirement to set account number with account text in first object of `headerList` ?

Comment: I want to have "account\(userAccountMoney)" in the header But I receive Error so used this : "account\(ProfileSettingTableViewController().userAccountMoney)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you cannot access instance property when you initialized another another property outside any method because complier don't know which one initialized the first, so what you need to do is declare `headerList` simply set the `account` string only as first object of array and latter changed it with new value.

```
var userAccountMoney = String()
var headerList = ["account" , "Help" , "" ]
```

Now in `viewDidLoad` simply replace the first object with new value.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let userAccount = profileViewController().userMoney

    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fa")
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
    numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: userAccount))
    userAccountMoney = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: userAccount))!
    self.headerList[0] = "account\(userAccountMoney)"
}
```

Comment: Thanks Its Working Well :)

Comment: and one more question how can I change Just userAccountMoney textColor ? I have viewForHeaderInSection function in my codes But I just can change the color of the all headers

Comment: You want change the textColor of all sectionHander or just first one?

Comment: No some thing harder :) I want to change just userAccountMoney in the first item of the header array it means that I want to account and help has their color But the userAccountMoney has Green Color

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Don't get you edit your question with some screenshot and what you want to change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144333/discussion-between-saeed-rahmatolahi-and-nirav-d).

Comment: for example See comments here : @SaeedRahmatolahi is Blue But the other words are black

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to revise [Swift documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html) regarding properties.

In your case you have a `local variable` whose life-cycle ends up at the end of the current scope declaration. Which means, if you declared a variable within `viewDidLoad` function, it will die at the end of the function execution.

**Update:**
Here comes a simple example of how to use it:

```
class MyViewController {
var userAccountMoney: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    userAccountMoney = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: userAccount))!
}

func otherFunc() {
    var headerList = [String(describing:"Account \(userAccountMoney)")]
}
}
```

Comment: so how can I Solve This Problem ?

Comment: I had Defined Variation OutSide View Did Load But couldn't use that in my Array

Comment: You should define the variable as class instance to be able to use it.

Comment: I used This But Didn't Worked too! in the header I have problem

Comment: Until you don't provide any more details which problems do you have, it's difficult to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you can take this variable outside the function and take as instance variable.

```
    class VC: ViewController {
    var userAccountMoney = String()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
          super.viewDidLoad() 
          userAccountMoney = numberFormatter.string(from:
NSNumber(value: userAccount))!

                }

//access userAccountMoney anyWhere in the instance function of view Controller
      }
```

Comment: I used This The problem is that I can't Use userAccountMoney in My Array 
                                                                                                                                   var headerList = ["Account\(userAccountMoney)"]

and I should use var Not Let (The app doesn't let me to use let)